# How can I create a colored histogram in plotly?

Tags: plotly, histogram, colorbar

I'm trying to figure out how to build a histogram with color bar similar to the figure below using plotly.

[image]

Comment: Are the colors based on the bin of each bar?

Answer (score 0):

- key to solution is to use **numpy** to generate **histogram**
- with this you can create a **bar** chart using **plotly express**
- your color scale is not a built in,  so have constructed using documented technique https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/#explicitly-constructing-a-color-scale

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

mu, sigma = 100, 50  # mean and standard deviation
s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)

# question shows a funky color scale...
color_scale = [
    c
    for c in zip(
        np.linspace(0, 0.5, len(px.colors.sequential.Blues[1:])),
        px.colors.sequential.Blues[1:][::-1],
    )
] + [
    c
    for c in zip(
        np.linspace(0.5, 1, len(px.colors.sequential.Reds[1:])),
        px.colors.sequential.Reds[1:],
    )
]

# use numpy to generate histogram
BINS = 30
y, x = np.histogram(s, bins=BINS)
# bin edges to midpoint
x = [(a + b) / 2 for a, b in zip(x, x[1:])]
px.bar(x=x, y=y, color=x, color_continuous_scale=color_scale).update_traces(
    marker_line_color="black"
).update_layout(bargap=0, coloraxis_cmid=mu)
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a bunch!